# Main content starts playing before preroll in video.js when using videojs-contrib-ads

Tags: video.js

When using videojs-contrib-ads to create an ad plugin in video.js, the main programme often starts playing before the ads start playing.  It seems that video.js connects to the CDN of the main content initially and then contrib-ads checks if it needs to play prerolls.  A few seconds of the main content is sometimes played before this happens and only then does it start to play the adverts.

This was seen mostly on iOS on live feeds.

Does anyone know why it works like this and is there a way to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [prerollTimeout](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-ads#prerolltimeout) setting.

> The maximum amount of time to wait for an ad implementation to initiate a postroll, in milliseconds. If contentended has been fired and the ad implementation does not call startLinearAdMode() before postrollTimeout expires, the content video will end playback.

Comment: We had prerollTimeout set to 100ms and we made sure that startLinearAdMode() was called straight away, but it would still play the main programme for a few seconds.  Unfortunately I don't have an example to show since we've changed the code since.  We saw this mostly on the iPhone on a live feed.  I'll update the question to say that.